# JAVA DecimalFormat Rounding Issue

Tags: java, decimalformat

I am trying to use a simple Decimal Formatter but getting unexpected results:

```
float amt = 61.0349998474121F;
    float amt1 = 4.5850000381470F;

    DecimalFormat m_numberFormat2DP = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
    System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP.getRoundingMode());
    System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP.format(amt));
    System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP.format(amt1));

    DecimalFormat m_numberFormat2DP1 = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    //m_numberFormat2DP1.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP1.getRoundingMode());
    System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP1.format(amt));//result should be 61.04
    System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP1.format(amt1));//result should be 4.59
```

This is my code tried half_up as well but the result is same the output I am receiving for last SOPs are 61.03 and 4.59. 61.03 should be 61.04

Comment: 61.03 and 4.59 seems correct to me

Comment: `61.03 should be 61.04` nope it shouldn't, `61.034` rounds to `61.03` whether you're rounding `HALF_UP` or not. You're probably looking for `CEILING`, where the value will be ceiled to the next integer rather than rounded.

Comment: Since you're trying to round 61.034999 to 61.04 it seems you want to get 2 fraction digits at max. Thus you could try to round your input + 0.001, i.e. 61.034999 + 0.001 = 61.035999 which then should round half-up to 61.04

Comment: Why 61.03 looks me to be correct as per round off

Comment: @Aaron `61.034999` should be 61.04 if you round it up correctly. first it is rounded to 61.035 and then to 61.04. yet it requires to be rounded up

Comment: @XtremeBaumer looks like we don't have the same definition of rounding correctly then. Rounding multiple times will lead to incorrections. 0.49999 < 0.5, it should be rounded to 0 rather than 1

Comment: well in germany you learn to round multiple times in school, otherwise you might get minus points for inaccurate result... if you have to round it in 1 go then you are right that it should be rounded down

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Please limit the scope to "I've learned in my school (or from my teacher)", because "in germany" is definitely wrong. You don't learn wrong rounding everywhere in germany.

Comment: @tom 3 different schools and several teacher and all said the same

Answer (score 0):

`61.034` will always be rounded to `61.03` because rounding brings to the nearest integer.

`HALF_UP`  / `HALF_DOWN` only impact values that are at the limit between two integers, i.e. `3.5` will be rounded to `4` with `HALF_UP` but to `3` with `HALF_DOWN`.

What you seems to be looking for is not a rounding function, but rather a ceiling function, where the value will be brought to the nearest above integer : `61.034` to `61.04`, `3.5` to `4`, etc.

Conveniently, the [RoundingMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html) enumeration provides such functionality to `DecimalFormat` with its `RoundingMode.CEILING` field :

```
DecimalFormat m_numberFormat2DP1 = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
m_numberFormat2DP1.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP1.getRoundingMode());
System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP1.format(amt));//result is 61.04
System.out.println(m_numberFormat2DP1.format(amt1));//result is 4.59
```

You can see it in action [here](https://ideone.com/iNT1xq).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DecimalFormatDemo {  
 public static void main(String args[]) {  
 DecimalFormat df1 = new DecimalFormat("###,###.0000");  
 System.out.println(df1.format(111111123456.12));  

 Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);  
 DecimalFormat df2= new DecimalFormat("###,###.0000");
 System.out.println(df2.format(111111123456.12));  

 DecimalFormat df3= new DecimalFormat();  
 myformat3.applyPattern("##,###.000");  
 System.out.println(df3.format(11112345.12345));  




  DecimalFormat df4= new DecimalFormat();  
  myformat4.applyPattern("0.000E0000");  
  System.out.println(df4.format(10000));  
  System.out.println(df4.format(12345678.345));  


  DecimalFormat df5= null;  
  try{  
     df5= (DecimalFormat)NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();  
 }catch(ClassCastException e){  
  <span style="white-space:pre">  </span> System.err.println(e);  
 }  
 df5.applyPattern("00.0000%");  
 System.out.println(df5.format(0.34567));  
 System.out.println(df5.format(1.34567));
```

}
}  **I hope I can help you**